# Spearman rank recommended n size

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, spearman-rho

Is there a recommended n to test for Spearman's rank correlation? I have 2 lists of around 10,000 items. I read that Spearman's rank correlation is fine between 10-30 , can I use spearman to compare ranked list of 100 or even 1000?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly you can. The only onerous part is computing all the ranks, but that's still pretty easy with ten thousand observations.

The questionable part would be why you'd *want* to test with 10000 pairs. Surely with almost any kind of non-artificial data, you're going to reject - few correlations are so small that they won't fall outside the limits for that. For example - at those sort of sample sizes you'll reject a correlation of around 0.02 as being significantly different from 0!

Surely the size of the correlation is more meaningful than whether you can reject it at such a big sample size?

Comment: OK. If the list is so long as I mentioned 10,000 or even 20,000 ,and when I compare the ranking of 30 items there is no spearman correlation , does it make sense to compare the ranking of 200 or 300 items? or usually users care about only top ranked items?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you have thousands, why only relate a few hundred (unless those are important *a priori*)? I can't speak to what users 'care about', doubly so when I have no context at all.